How to generate assembly code with the clang invocation recorded in the output?
How can I run clang so that the generated assembly code contains the invocation command line somewhere in its output?
Example of running clang and not getting the desired information:
$ echo "int main(void){}" | clang -xc++ - -S -o xxx.S

$ head xxx.S
    .text
    .file   "-"
    .globl  main                            # -- Begin function main
    .p2align    4, 0x90
    .type   main,@function
main:                                   # @main

Here we see that xxx.S doesn't contain the following (or similar) line:
.invoc "clang -xc++ - -S -o xxx.S"

OR
# compiler invocation: clang -xc++ - -S -o xxx.S

How to generate .invoc "xxx" OR # compiler invocation: xxx (or similar)? Is it possible at all?  (Here, .invoc is just a hypothetical directive that would contain the needed information.)
NOTE: Some C compilers do that by default.

@ScottMcPeak Indeed. I've badly formulated the question. Fixed.

@ScottMcPeak The .invoc is just an example. It may have a different name. It may be not a directive at all, but rather a comment (e.g. # compiler invocation: xxx). The question is about whether it is possible at all with Clang by having a generated artifact (files .S, .o, etc.) to know how the Clang was invoked when generating this artifact.

clang will emit assembly containing its command line when invoked with the -frecord-command-line option.  Quoting its documentation:

-frecord-command-line, -fno-record-command-line, -frecord-gcc-switches
Generate a section named “.GCC.command.line” containing the clang driver command-line. After linking, the section may contain multiple command lines, which will be individually terminated by null bytes. Separate arguments within a command line are combined with spaces; spaces and backslashes within an argument are escaped with backslashes. This format differs from the format of the equivalent section produced by GCC with the -frecord-gcc-switches flag. This option is currently only supported on ELF targets.

Example:
$ cat test.c
void f(void){}

$ clang -S -frecord-command-line test.c

$ tail test.s
        .cfi_endproc
                                        # -- End function
        .ident  "clang version 16.0.0"
        .section        .GCC.command.line,"MS",@progbits,1
        .zero   1
        .ascii  "/home/scott/opt/clang+llvm-16.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04/bin/clang-16 -S -frecord-command-line test.c"
        .zero   1
        .text
        .section        ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
        .addrsig

It is perhaps noteworthy that the clang in my PATH is a symlink in my $HOME/bin directory to the clang in the Clang bin directory, which is itself a symlink to clang-16, and it is the latter that ends up in the assembly output.  At least on Linux, Clang uses /proc/self/exe (see Unix/Path.inc) to find the executable name, rather than relying on argv[0].

Just a note: the -frecord-command-line is not mentioned in man clang: man clang | grep 'frecord-command-line' produces nothing. For the end user this may be unexpected.

Just a note: clang --help | grep 'frecord-command-line' also produces nothing.
